# How can I show that $E[\sup_{0 \le t \le T} N_t^2]<\infty$ for all $T>0$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Given a Stochastic differential equation 
$dN_t=\sqrt{2\mu N}dW_t$ starting with a deterministic initial value $N_O$.

How can I show that $E[\sup_{0 \le t \le T} N_t^2]<\infty$ for all $T>0$?
I know that there exists a unique strong non-negative solution to the SDE and that its solution has a non-central chi-squared conditional distribution. How can I bound $E[\sup_{0 \le t \le T} N_t^2]$ by above given a T and do this for every $T>0$. Any hints would be appreciated

Comment: Show your working on finding the solution $N_t$. I suspect it is a matter of looking up the second moment of the non-central chi squared distribution and maximising under $t$

Comment: I actually am not sure if it’s true .  I tried playing around with the conditional variance of the solution but gave up since I wasn’t sure if the statement is even true

Comment: Ok no worries I will have a go with solving the SDE for you when i get home.

Comment: Thank you . I am going to try a little more in the meanwhile

Comment: Note that $N$ is a martingale and hence Doob's maximal inequality can be applied.